# Find graph of inverse function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: Here is the question:]

[image: Here are the answer choices:]

I don't understand the concept of inverse functions. I don't know how to fold the graph about the line y=x. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is for a probability class?

Comment: Draw the line y=x. Then, from some point on the plot of your function travel up to the y=x line. When you get there, however far you traveled up, travel to the left by that distance and put a point. If you had to travel down to get to the y=x line, then however far down you traveled, travel to the right that distance and place a point.

Answer (score 1):

These aren't inverse functions, they're inverse relations, but your idea of reflecting the graph about the line $y=x$ is a good one. That's the line with slope one exactly bisecting the first and third quadrants.
Try focusing on one part of the graph at a time. By that I mean, pick one "branch" and draw its mirror image reflected along $y=x$.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew 20:16 “So the last will be first, and the first will be last.”

And so it is with inverse functions/relations. "the $x$ shall be $y$ and  the $y$ shall be $x$". Just switch the $x$'s and $y$'s, and solve for the new $y$.

For example, to find the inverse of $$y=2x+3$$
just reverse the $x$s and $y$s
$$x=2y+3$$
$$x-3=2y$$
$$\frac{x-3}{2}=y$$
$$y=\frac{x-3}{2}$$

Another way of "reflecting" about the $y=x$ line, is to plot the points in reverse order. For example, if $(1,-5)$ is a point on the graph of the "function", then the point $(-5,1)$ is a point on the "inverse of the function". If all else fails, put the paper with the graph up to the light, turn the page over, and look at the graph with the x-axis in the vertical position.

On my website, I have a short article that I wrote on inverse functions, maybe worth checking out. http://mathuprising.comlu.com/inverse-functions.html

Just for kicks, try to "see" the endpoints and plot them backwards.
[image]

Comment: This was to be my inauguration speech, but I decided not to run for President, hoping to become the Baseball Commissioner instead.

Comment: Except the OP wasn't given a closed form nor points, so this method probably isn't helpful for him or her.